# JS - Compare Objects with an additional ID

Tags: javascript, object, compare

I get no further to compare the following objects with an additional ID:

```js
let id = 123
conterForCompareObjects = 0
conterForHitsValue2 = 0

value1: {
  '0': [999],
  '3': [123]
}
value2: {
  '0': {id: 999, something: "ABC"}, 
  '1': {id: 000, something: "DEF"},
  '2': {id: 123, something: "GHI"},
  '3': {id: 123, something: "JKL"}
}
```

I would like to count two different things:

1. How often is the id on the same position (in my example it is number '3' in this objects (I expect one)
2. How often is the id in value2 (I expect two).

Can someone help me or can give me a good hint how I can solve this issues? I tried with filter, but I think I am doing something wrong:

```js
value1.filter( val1 => val1.includes(id))
```

and then I get no further to compare it with value2 :/

Comment: value1.filter( val1 => val1.includes(id)) and then i get no further to compare it with value2 :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `filter` method cannot be used on an `Object`, it is a property of an `Array`.

Please note below is a general solution. It will keep count for all the keys. So use it or modify it as per your needs.

1. How often is the id on the same position (in my example it is number '3' in this objects (I expect one)

The number of hit will always be 1 since we are only checking if the ID exists in both objects.

```
let compareMap = new Map();
let conterForCompareObjects = new Map();

for(let postion in value1){
  let id = value1[position][0];
  compareMap.set(position, id);
}

for(let position in value2){
  let id1 = compareMap.get(position);
  if(id1 !== undefined){
   let id2 = value2[position]['id'];
    if(id2 === id1){
      conterForCompareObjects.set(id2, 1);
    } else conterForCompareObjects.set(id2, 0); // or don't, in that case it's `undefined`
  }
}

let someID = <SOME ID IN value2>
let hitForSomeID = conterForCompareObjects.get(someID);
```

2. How often is the id in value2 (I expect two).

```
let conterForHitsValue2 = new Map();

for(let position in value2){
  let id = value2[position]['id'];
  let count = conterForHitsValue2.get(id);
  if(count === undefined){
    conterForHitsValue2.set(id, 0);
  } else {
    conterForHitsValue2.set(id, count + 1);
  }
}

let someID = <SOME ID IN value2>
let hitForSomeID = conterForHitsValue2.get(someID);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and the hint with filter on objects;-)

Comment: @Beer-Hunter There were few errors and I have also refactored code to make it more clear.